# Error in running the example code of as_image

Tags: r, flextable

I am trying to run the example code in R( R studio version: 2023.06.1+524; R version: 4.2.1; flextable version: 0.9.2):

```
img.file <- file.path( R.home("doc"),
  "html", "logo.jpg" )
if (require("magick")) {
  myft <- flextable( head(iris))
  myft <- compose( myft, i = 1:3, j = 1,
   value = as_paragraph(
     as_image(src = img.file),
     " ",
     as_chunk(Sepal.Length,
       props = fp_text_default(color = "red"))
   ),
   part = "body")
  ft <- autofit(myft)
  ft
}
```

And then i meet an error:

```
Error in as_chunk(Sepal.Length, props = fp_text_default(color = "red")) : 
  object 'Sepal.Length' not found
```

So are there something wrong? What should I do?
Thank you!

Comment: The code works fine for me using `flextable` `0.9.2`.

Comment: `as_chunk('Sepal.Length', props=` seems to work instead of Sepal.Length without quotes. `flextable 0.8.2`

Comment: The code is working fine for me. Try checking your `myft` object after `myft <- flextable(head(iris))` whether it has `Sepal.Length` or not. Because the error is indicating that the Sepal.Length object is not created before the use of 'compose' function.

Comment: this is cross-posted here: https://github.com/davidgohel/flextable/issues/567. 'purrr' is probably loaded and `compose` should be replaced by `flextable::compose()` or `mk_par()`.

Comment: Thanks！I've solved the problem following @DavidGohel.